# Regex match value between range with fixed increments

Tags: regex, numbers, range, increment

I have been stuck on this for a while, but I want to write a Regex expression that:

- Accept values between 200-10000
  AND
- Number only true when there is a 100 increment, e.g. 200, 3700, 9900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like this: `^(?:[2-9]|\d{2}|100)00$`, where you match:

- a digit in range [2, 9] followed by two zeroes, or
- two digits followed by two zeroes, or
- ten thousand

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below regex pattern,

^([2-9][0][0]|[1-9][0-9][0][0]|[1][0][0][0][0])$

It will accept values between 200 - 10000 and returns TRUE if the input is like 9000.

Suppose if you want only hundreds to be allowed like 9100, 9200 and not 9000, you can use the below regex pattern.

^([2-9][0][0]|[1-9][1-9][0][0]|[1][0][0][0][0])$